# How to upload apk to crashlytics using Curl?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm trying to upload an APK to crashlytics with fastlane but i have some error that i cant resolve.
Also the official solution ([doc](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/ant.html)) it is not good for me because the apk is already builded.

Is there a solution using curl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. We don't have a solution for uploading the APK via curl. However, you can upload built APKs through the Android Studio plugin. From command line,  we only support using Fastlane or uploads from the build flow in Ant, Maven or Gradle.

Comment: There is that very helpful `Crashlytics.framework/submit` tool for iOS — why did you not create the same for Android? That's a real pain.